# Multiple exposed filters - An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that I am using two exposed "Has taxonomy term" filters. The view works fine. I get the correct data. Except this error keeps popping up:

```
An illegal choice has been detected
Please contact the site administrator
```

If I look at the actual error, the message is this:

```
Illegal choice *some_tid* in tid element.
```

The thing is, the "some_tid" actually exists, so I don't know why it is throwing the error. And I honestly don't care. Like I said the view is working fine. I just want the error to go away.

Now I don't get the error if I use Ajax on the form. However, I don't want to use Ajax as I will be building a menu that injects specific tids into the view. So I want to be able to make a like this to the view and have it pull up the results: testing-views?tid=29&tid_1=14